# Get location from where msi installer is being launched

Tags: visual-c++, windows-installer

I'm making an msi installer using VC++ which copies a *.jar file into a specified destination. The *.jar file is provided with the msi installer(Duh!). But I need to find the location from which the msi installer is being launched. For example, if I provide the whole setup in a DVD, and the user puts the DVD in the drive, and his\her DVD drive is G:\, I need the installer to know that it is launched from "G:" drive so that it should look within G:\ for the *.jar file. The objective is to make the msi installer launch from anywhere so that the necessary path, from which the support files need to be copied, can be obtained. Currently, the msi installer is being launched from a *.cpp file and I have mentioned the path where the *.jar file is located specifically to the msi installer (in otherwords, hardcoded the path within the c++ program). I need to obtain the path in realtime. I'm a beginner. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. Got the answer to my problem. I created two "Add Registry search" in the Launch conditions tab. The first property was named as **JREVERSION** in the property, **SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment** as the RegKey and **CurrentVersion** as the Value set in the Properties tab. 
The second property was named **JREVERSIONPATH** in the Property, and as for RegKey, **SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\[JREVERSION]** was given and for Value, **JavaHome** was specified. So, **JREVERSION** returns the latest version number and this property was used in the path of **JREVERSIONPATH** to find the **JavaHome**, which contains the required directory path. 
Finally, on the File System Tab, **[JREVERSIONPATH]** was given as the value of **DefaultLocation**.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing because C++ is a language / compiler used to make program executables on Windows.  It doesn't make MSI's.

From an MSI perspective you would want to look at the SourceDir or possibly the OriginalDatabase property to find where your installer is running from.